# Discord: Change region using .NET library?

Tags: c#, discord, region, discord.net

I'm currently trying to prevent lags on my Discord server using a bot checking the latency, and switching to another region if it does happen. I saw a couple of bots in js doing that, I'd like to know if there's something in Discord.NET able to do it. Of course, I've been parsing Google for hours to find a way.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can call `ModifyAsync` on an instance of your `SocketGuild` and set the `RegionId` property to your desired new region.

```cs
//I'm doing this as a command, but the logic can be implemented wherever you decide.
[Command("region")]
[Remarks("Let's pretend my module has access to a singleton instance of random")]
public async Task ChangeRegion()
{
    //Get a collection of all available voice regions 
    //Exclude the region we are currently in
    var voiceRegions = Context.Client.VoiceRegions.Where(r => !r.Id.Equals(Context.Guild.VoiceRegionId));

    //Select a random new region
    var newRegion = voiceRegions(random.Next(voiceRegions.Count));

    //Update the RegionId property for the guild.
    await Context.Guild.ModifyAsync(prop => prop.RegionId = newRegion.Id)
    await ReplyAsync($"Region updated to {newRegion.Name}: {newRegion.Id}");
}
```